# How do I format a list of dates into timestamp format?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, format, key

If I create a list, timeSeries, can I change its format?

```
timeSeries = pd.date_range(mindate, maxdate, freq="3H")
```

The items in this look like this:

```
'2021-05-18 00:00:00+00:00'
```

How do I get it to look like this:

```
Timestamp('2021-05-18 00:00:00')
```

Comment: They are already Timestamp objects. The representation in text shows the strings, but if you index the `date_range` with `[0]` you will see that the first item is in fact a `pd.Timestamp`.

Comment: You can use `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` to get the same format.

Comment: My problem is I have multiple dictionaries with the time as the key, formatted as Timestamp('2022-05-17 22:00:00'), so when I make my timeSeries, I need it to look like that as well because it is not letting me query by the items in the timeSeries because they look different.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem with the `+00:00` when I use the `timeSeries` line and then take the first item, `timeSeries[0]`.  My output is `Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', freq='3H')` using `"2020-01-01"` as the start date and `"2020-01-02"` as the end.